# Bootstrap modal in html page

Tags: spring, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I am trying to insert a modal into a html page. I took the example from bootstrap page:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's not working(nothing pops up). I also use thymeleaf in my project and i think there is the problem but i don't know what it is. Thanks.

Comment: What is the complete HTML page, from `<html>` to `</html>`, as shown when you right-click and select "view page source" in your browser?

Comment: Make sure you include both jquery.js and bootstrap.js into your html for the modal to work.

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot to include jquery.js in my html :(